# Constant running process on a sperate thread blocking a UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

i am trying to use a third party telnet library "active expert" for a basic telnet session. 
in my UI code behind i have something like

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        var ts = new TelnetService();
        await ts.DoConnect(node);
    }
```

and my TelnetService looks like this

```
    public class TelnetService
{
    private Tcp objSocket = new Tcp();
    private NwConstants objConstants = new NwConstants();
    public string Responses { get; set; }
    private Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    public TelnetService()
    {
        timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Elapsed;
        timer1.Interval = 100;
        timer1.Start();
    }
    void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (objSocket.ConnectionState == objConstants.nwSOCKET_CONNSTATE_CONNECTED)
        {
            if (objSocket.HasData())
            {
                Responses += objSocket.ReceiveString() + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }

    public Task DoConnect(Node node)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           objSocket.Protocol = objConstants.nwSOCKET_PROTOCOL_TELNET;
           objSocket.Connect(node.IP, 23);

           while (true)
           {
               if ((Responses == null) || (!Responses.Contains(node.WaitString))) continue;
               //do something
               Responses = "";
               break;
           }
       });
    }

}
```

there are two important pieces of functionalities.

First in the **timer1_Elapsed** function which is process that will keeps on ruining and checks if there is data on socket, and if there is, it will append it to a string "Response". and i am using "timer" for it.

Second in the **DoConnect** function which will check the"Response" string for a certain input. for this i am using async await and Task.

in a nutshell first one accumulating the Response and Second one checking the Response.

Problem is that it looks like the timer code in general and

```
objSocket.ReceiveString()
```

line specifically is causing the UI thread to halt for several seconds. which means after clicking the button i cannot move my main form on the screen however the code is running in a separate thread. 
i have tried using pure Thread for this but it didn't helped either.

**update**

instead of timer i am using a method AccumulateResponse

```
public static void AccumulateResponse()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (objSocket.ConnectionState == objConstants.nwSOCKET_CONNSTATE_CONNECTED)
            {
                if (objSocket.HasData())
                {
                    Responses += objSocket.ReceiveString() + "\r\n";
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and calling it like

```
   var t = new Task(TelnetService.AccumulateResponse);           
        t.Start();
        await TelnetService.DoConnect(node);
```

still no luck

Comment: Invoke `.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);` in `DoConnect()` when creating a new task. This will avoid using the Default synchronization context which is main thread. See this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The `DoConnect` isn't your problem.  It is your Timer Elapsed Event handler.

The timer elapsed event is NOT asynchronous.  Only the `DoConnect` is.

If there is no asynchronous version of `ReceiveString()` from your third party lib, then use `Task.Run` there as well inside of an `async timer1_elapsed` method.

Comment: sure ill try that and will let you know

Comment: if ill use Task.Run inside elapsed it will run a task on each Tick . do we want that ?

Comment: Not terribly as long as you await them. [Why](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) ...although I might use task.wait like he says in the other blog entry since his isn't really CPU bound work.